# Cannot open settings and gnome-control-center in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, settings

When I attempt to open settings, the icon spins for some seconds and disappears afterwards.

In terminal I used the command

```
gnome-control-center
```

and this error shows up:

> gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libndr-standard.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I use grep to search for `libndr-standard.so.0` but there is no such file in /etc.

I also tried

```
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

as suggested by other posts but it did not work.

This problem occurred after a system update. I am not aware of what exactly was updated. Apart from settings disappearing, the system freezes a lot more frequently (i.e. keyboard and mouses stop working).

My system is ubuntu 18.04 and uses nvidia-driver-470 (the latest).
I am running out of ideas of what else I could try. Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned *libndr-standard.so.0* [is contained](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libndr-standard.so.0) in `samba-libs` package.

You have to reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs
```

and then retry to launch GNOME Control Center.

Comment: A million thanks, @N0rbert!! It worked like a charm.